# how to replace a word in string in php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php  
        $querysb=mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM services WHERE cid='".$_GET[id]."'");
        $rowsb=mysql_fetch_assoc($querysb);
        ?>
           <center><h2> 
           <?php $str=$rowsb['cname'];
            $str = mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE);
            echo $str;?></center></h2>
```

the output of this code is **Hello/hi World** but i want this to be **Hello/Hi World**.

Comment: Did you use google to find an answer? Also `mysql_` is deprecated and removed asof PHP 7. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead

Comment: `ucwords($str); ` use this

Comment: yes! and i got suggestion to use str_replace. but it didn't worked@superDJ

Comment: this is basic question with no research. Just use php.net  where you can find `str_replace()` and most of the function are implemented there.

Comment: str_replace does work and is one of the most often used PHP functions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look on [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) function

```
<?php

$str = 'Hello/hi World';

echo ucwords($str, '/');
```

**output**

```
Hello/Hi World
```

seet result at: https://3v4l.org/XhORd

Comment: ThanX Chetan it worked. Just a little  doublt,if i want to hi in uppercase (both h&i) what changes i need to make?

Comment: You need to play around strtoupper, strtolower ect functions

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use ucwords() function

> string ucwords ( string $str [, string $delimiters = " \t\r\n\f\v" ] )

[PHP ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)